# Automatically move title text to next page/column if it originally appears on the last line of page/column

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Is it possible to have InDesign automatically move a title (with associated paragraph style) to the next page/column if it would otherwise appear on the last line of a page/column?

Many of my titles in a book I am working on end up being on the last line of the column/page. I want to have them automatically shifted to the next column/page when this happens. Is it possible to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Paragraph Style Options > Keep Options > Start Paragraph** to *always* make a paragraph start on for example the next page/column.

[image]

But you ask for it to *only* happen if the paragraph ends up being the last line of a column/page. This can indirectly be done using **Paragraph Style Options > Keep Options > Keep with Next**.

Here you can specify how many lines you want to *at least* follow directly after the title. If there isn't room for the specified number of lines, the paragraph will jump to the next column/frame/page.

[image]